# Storing Typekit font in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently using a Typekit font inside of rails. The font is, from the JS:

```
(function(d) {
  var config = {
      kitId: 'vzq7eog',
      scriptTimeout: 3000
    },
    h = d.documentElement,
    t = setTimeout(function() {
        h.className = h.className.replace(/\bwf-loading\b/g, "") + " wf-inactive";
    }, config.scriptTimeout),
    tk = d.createElement("script"),
    f = false,
    s = d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],
    a;
  h.className += " wf-loading";
  tk.src = '//use.typekit.net/' + config.kitId + '.js';
  tk.async = true;
  tk.onload = tk.onreadystatechange = function() {
    a = this.readyState;
    if (f || a && a != "complete" && a != "loaded") return;
    f = true;
    clearTimeout(t);
    try {
      Typekit.load(config)
    } catch (e) {}
  };
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(tk, s)
})(document);
```

What I don't like about this is that it sends off an API request to typekit. What I'm wondering is how I would go about storing this is something like the vendor folder inside of rails.

Comment: Storing the response? Or the javascript?

Comment: Done :) After doing that, it looks like there's more API requests that are done by Typekit. One of my problems with this service is that they don't minimize the amount of requests they perform. I'm already storing their initial JS request now, but I'm hoping someone has already been able to get everything to load from 1 API request instead of Adobe's 5.

Comment: Put it in the `public` folder? Or `vendor/assets`?

Comment: @jwadsack read comment I made above. It wasn't that simple...

Comment: Could you post your solution in case others come across this issue?

Comment: @jwadsack It wasn't a solution. Its a simple fix a lot of people would do, but the problem is that it ended up causing more overhead. I don't think this question is resolved yet.